# Compiler error: Same identity, EnvDTE80

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, vsx

Trying to follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961.aspx), under the section "Initializing the Project Factory" I've added EnvDTE to my project, but now I get this error:

> An assembly with the same identity 'EnvDTE80, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

Even if I remove all the references to it, I still get it. It must be somewhere in the project base or something? What's creating two+ references to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this particular error by unloading the project, editing the `.csproj` xml file and removing the reference to EnvDTE in there.

Comment: worked for me too. I've removed the reference to EnvDTE80 and now it works. P.S. - it's already your second post which helped me with vs packages. Thanks.